# Flask C++ Socket Code 400, message Bad request syntax

Tags: python, c++, sockets, flask

I'm trying to connect a Flask server with C++ client through a socket connection:

Server:

```
from flask import Flask
from os.path import dirname, abspath
from queue import Queue
import base64
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import io
from object_detection import detect_object

d = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.queue = Queue()

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello"

@app.route("/")
def test_live(message):
    app.queue.put(message['data'])
    img_bytes = base64.b64decode(app.queue.get())
    img_np = np.array(Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes)))
    img_np = detect_object(img_np)
    frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))[
        1
    ].tobytes()
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(frame)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(app, host = '127.0.0.1', port = 5000, debug = True)
```

C++ client

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void main()
{
    string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";         // IP Address of the server
    int port = 5000;                        // Listening port # on the server

    // Initialize WinSock
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Create socket
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Fill in a hint structure
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    // Connect to server
    int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Do-while loop to send and receive data
    char buf[4096];
    string userInput;

    do
    {
        // Prompt the user for some text
        cout << "> ";

        getline(cin, userInput);

        if (userInput.size() > 0)       // Make sure the user has typed in something
        {
            // Send the text
            Mat frame;
            frame = imread(userInput.c_str(), IMREAD_COLOR);
            int imgSize = frame.total() * frame.elemSize();

            int sendResult = send(sock, (const char*) frame.data, imgSize, 0);

            if (sendResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                // Wait for response
                ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
                int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    // Echo response to console
                    cout << "SERVER> " << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;
                }
            }
        }

    } while (userInput.size() > 0);

    // Gracefully close down everything
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

I'm getting this error on the server when I try to send a image from the client:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 11:45:40] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('54043/0.--+*/--1//2-.2-./+**(\'#! \x19\x1c\x1a\x12\x19\x16\x0f\x1a\x17\x13 \x1e\x14%"\x16*+\x17,-\x180.\x1830\x1b63\x1c96\x1b:7\x1c;8\x1e?;\x1eA= C?\x1fGB#JH&QN*WT-\\Y2_\\5b_9ga<jd>jc>jc>jc>jc7e_6f`9ic:mf;oh:ng9pg;riCxn<qg;sh=uj:ti=wlB{sC|t?ytB|wE}xBzu@yq@yq?xo:vl7rj;wo;wo;wo;vn7rj5nf0f_+^Z\'VS\'TQ\'OM%LJ\x1eCA\x1c<;\x1654\x17//\x15--\x13--\x1400\x13++')
    127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 11:45:40] "54043/0.--+*/--1//2-.2-./+**('#!  %"*+,-0.306396:7;8?;A= C?GB#JH&QN*WT-\Y2_\5b_9ga<jd>jc>jc>jc>jc7e_6f`9ic:mf;oh:ng9pg;riCxn<qg;sh=uj:ti=wlB{sC|t?ytB|wE}xBzu@yq@yq?xo:vl7rj;wo;wo;wo;vn7rj5nf0f_+^Z'VS'TQ'OM%LJCA<;54//----00++" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
    127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 11:46:00] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('54043/0.--+*/--1//2-.2-./+**(\'#! \x19\x1c\x1a\x12\x19\x16\x0f\x1a\x17\x13 \x1e\x14%"\x16*+\x17,-\x180.\x1830\x1b63\x1c96\x1b:7\x1c;8\x1e?;\x1eA= C?\x1fGB#JH&QN*WT-\\Y2_\\5b_9ga<jd>jc>jc>jc>jc7e_6f`9ic:mf;oh:ng9pg;riCxn<qg;sh=uj:ti=wlB{sC|t?ytB|wE}xBzu@yq@yq?xo:vl7rj;wo;wo;wo;vn7rj5nf0f_+^Z\'VS\'TQ\'OM%LJ\x1eCA\x1c<;\x1654\x17//\x15--\x13--\x1400\x13++')
    127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020 11:46:00] "54043/0.--+*/--1//2-.2-./+**('#!  %"*+,-0.306396:7;8?;A= C?GB#JH&QN*WT-\Y2_\5b_9ga<jd>jc>jc>jc>jc7e_6f`9ic:mf;oh:ng9pg;riCxn<qg;sh=uj:ti=wlB{sC|t?ytB|wE}xBzu@yq@yq?xo:vl7rj;wo;wo;wo;vn7rj5nf0f_+^Z'VS'TQ'OM%LJCA<;54//----00++" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

I have read that's because my client is trying to connect via HTTPS but I don't find how to change it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You use " getline(cin, userInput);", but instead you should probably just set userInput to something in your C++ code. We can't see what you type to your program, so it's hard to know what happens or reproduce what's happening.

Comment: You need to send some kind of HTTP protocol string over the socket. Like a "GET"

Comment: I'm using getline just to write the path of an Image on my disk. That path is what I use later on: frame = imread(userInput.c_str(), IMREAD_COLOR);

Comment: Ah, that explains your problem. You Python program expects to talk the *HTTP* protocol, with maybe a PUT or a POST or something. Instead you are just giving it image data, without an HTTP path or anything. Also, I'm not sure your Python program is configured to receive a PUT or POST, I don't remember exactly how Flask works. You could probably make this easier by using an HTTP library for C++, like for instance https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib  (but you can do it with plain sockets too, but it's a little bit harder) Good luck!